# Parse Nested JSON Data of Share Market Data

Tags: json, excel, vba

I want to web **scrape** the, some call and puts data of the stock very fast,so i successfully passed the URL and got Json response text,it has large amount of arrays,further i dont know how to get the required value from the data only for the particular expiry date (Here i want to take only for the date 30-Sep-2021).

And i want to extract all elements in inside CE and PE arrays with respect to expiry 30-sep-2021 for all strike prices
in the excel cells as a table LIKE BELOW
[image]

Table in the web site for ur reference
[image]

Here le me give you the Json data which is to be parsed

```
{
"records":{
"expiryDates":[
"30-Sep-2021",
"28-Oct-2021"
],
"data":[
{
"strikePrice":1280,
"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021",
"CE":{
"strikePrice":1280,
"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021",
"underlying":"ACC",
"identifier":"OPTSTKACC30-09-2021CE1280.00",
"openInterest":0,
"changeinOpenInterest":0,
"pchangeinOpenInterest":0,
"totalTradedVolume":0,
"impliedVolatility":0,
"lastPrice":0,
"change":0,
"pChange":0,
"totalBuyQuantity":10000,
"totalSellQuantity":10000,
"bidQty":10000,
"bidprice":1041.25,
"askQty":10000,
"askPrice":1339.75,
"underlyingValue":2467.9
},
"PE":{
"strikePrice":1280,
"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021",
"underlying":"ACC",
"identifier":"OPTSTKACC30-09-2021PE1280.00",
"openInterest":0,
"changeinOpenInterest":0,
"pchangeinOpenInterest":0,
"totalTradedVolume":0,
"impliedVolatility":0,
"lastPrice":0,
"change":0,
"pChange":0,
"totalBuyQuantity":5000,
"totalSellQuantity":0,
"bidQty":5000,
"bidprice":0.1,
"askQty":0,
"askPrice":0,
"underlyingValue":2467.9
}
},
{
"strikePrice":1300,
"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021",
"PE":{
"strikePrice":1300,
"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021",
"underlying":" ACC",
"identifier":"OPTSTKACC30-09-2021PE1300.00",
"openInterest":0,
"changeinOpenInterest":0,
"pchangeinOpenInterest":0,
"totalTradedVolume":0,
"impliedVolatility":0,
"lastPrice":0,
"change":0,
"pChange":0,
"totalBuyQuantity":8000,
"totalSellQuantity":500,
"bidQty":3000,
"bidprice":0.15,
"askQty":500,
"askPrice":2,
"underlyingValue":2467.9
},
"CE":{
"strikePrice":1300,
"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021",
"underlying":"ACC",
"identifier":"OPTSTKACC30-09-2021CE1300.00",
"openInterest":0,
"changeinOpenInterest":0,
"pchangeinOpenInterest":0,
"totalTradedVolume":0,
"impliedVolatility":0,
"lastPrice":0,
"change":0,
"pChange":0,
"totalBuyQuantity":10000,
"totalSellQuantity":10000,
"bidQty":10000,
"bidprice":1017.35,
"askQty":10000,
"askPrice":1337.4,
"underlyingValue":2467.9
}
},
{
"strikePrice":1320,
"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021",
"CE":{
"strikePrice":1320,
"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021",
"underlying":"ACC",
"identifier":"OPTSTKACC30-09-2021CE1320.00",
"openInterest":0,
"changeinOpenInterest":0,
"pchangeinOpenInterest":0,
"totalTradedVolume":0,
"impliedVolatility":0,
"lastPrice":0,
"change":0,
"pChange":0,
"totalBuyQuantity":10000,
"totalSellQuantity":10000,
"bidQty":10000,
"bidprice":999.45,
"askQty":10000,
"askPrice":1300.85,
"underlyingValue":2467.9
},
"PE":{
"strikePrice":1320,
"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021",
"underlying":"ACC",
"identifier":"OPTSTKACC30-09-2021PE1320.00",
"openInterest":0,
"changeinOpenInterest":0,
"pchangeinOpenInterest":0,
"totalTradedVolume":0,
"impliedVolatility":0,
"lastPrice":0,
"change":0,
"pChange":0,
"totalBuyQuantity":5000,
"totalSellQuantity":0,
"bidQty":5000,
"bidprice":0.1,
"askQty":0,
"askPrice":0,
"underlyingValue":2467.9
}
},
{
"strikePrice":1340,
"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021",
"PE":{
"strikePrice":1340,
"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021",
"underlying":"ACC",
"identifier":"OPTSTKACC30-09-2021PE1340.00",
"openInterest":0,
"changeinOpenInterest":0,
"pchangeinOpenInterest":0,
"totalTradedVolume":0,
"impliedVolatility":0,
"lastPrice":0,
"change":0,
"pChange":0,
"totalBuyQuantity":5000,
"totalSellQuantity":0,
"bidQty":5000,
"bidprice":0.1,
"askQty":0,
"askPrice":0,
"underlyingValue":2467.9
},
"CE":{
"strikePrice":1340,
"ex piryDate":"30-Sep-2021",
"underlying":"ACC",
"identifier":"OPTSTKACC30-09-2021CE1340.00",
"openInterest":0,
"changeinOpenInterest":0,
"pchangeinOpenInterest":0,
"totalTradedVolume":0,
"impliedVolatility":0,
"lastPrice":0,
"change":0,
"pChange":0,
"totalBuyQuantity":10000,
"totalSellQuantity":10000,
"bidQty":10000,
"bidprice":985.2,
"askQty":10000,
"askPrice":1271.65,
"underlyingValue":2467.9
}
},
{
"strikePrice":1360,
"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021",
"CE":{
"strikePrice":1360,
"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021",
"underlying":"ACC",
"identifier":"OPTSTKACC30-09-2021CE1360.00",
"openInterest":0,
"changeinOpenInterest":0,
"pchangeinOpenInterest":0,
"totalTradedVolume":0,
"impliedVolatility":0,
"lastPrice":0,
"change":0,
"pChange":0,
"totalBuyQuantity":10000,
"totalSellQuantity":10000,
"bidQty":10000,
"bidprice":973.75,
"askQty":10000,
"askPrice":1262.15,
"underlyingValue":2467.9
},
"PE":{
"strikePrice":1360,
"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021",
"underlying":"ACC",
"identifier":"OPTSTKACC30-09-2021PE1360.00",
"openInterest":0,
"changeinOpenInterest":0,
"pchangeinOpenInterest":0,
"tota lTradedVolume":0,
"impliedVolatility":0,
"lastPrice":0,
"change":0,
"pChange":0,
"totalBuyQuantity":5000,
"totalSellQuantity":0,
"bidQty":5000,
"bidprice":0.1,
"askQty":0,
"askPrice":0,
"underlyingValue":2467.9
}
},
{
"strikePrice":1380,
"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021",
"PE":{
"strikePrice":1380,
"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021",
"underlying":"ACC",
"identifier":"OPTSTKACC30-09-2021PE1380.00",
"openInterest":0,
"changeinOpenInterest":0,
"pchangeinOpenInterest":0,
"totalTradedVolume":0,
"impliedVolatility":0,
"lastPrice":0,
"change":0,
"pChange":0,
"totalBuyQuantity":5000,
"totalSellQuantity":0,
"bidQty":5000,
"bidprice":0.1,
"askQty":0,
"askPrice":0,
"underlyingValue":2467.9
},
"CE":{
"strikePrice":1380,
"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021",
"underlying":"ACC",
"identifier":"OPTSTKACC30-09-2021CE1380.00",
"openInterest":0,
"changeinOpenInterest":0,
"pchangeinOpenInterest":0,
"totalTradedVolume":0,
"impliedVolatility":0,
"lastPrice":0,
"change":0,
"pChange":0,
"totalBuyQuantity":10000,
"totalSellQuantity":10000,
"bidQty":10000,
"bidprice":956.2,
"askQty":10000,
"askPrice":1234.1,
"unde rlyingValue":2467.9
}
},
{
"strikePrice":1400,
"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021",
"CE":{
"strikePrice":1400,
"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021",
"underlying":"ACC",
"identifier":"OPTSTKACC30-09-2021CE1400.00",
"openInterest":0,
"changeinOpenInterest":0,
"pchangeinOpenInterest":0,
"totalTradedVolume":0,
"impliedVolatility":0,
"lastPrice":0,
"change":0,
"pChange":0,
"totalBuyQuantity":10000,
"totalSellQuantity":10000,
"bidQty":10000,
"bidprice":932.75,
"askQty":10000,
"askPrice":1217.75,
"underlyingValue":2467.9
},
"PE":{
"strikePrice":1400,
"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021",
"underlying":"ACC",
"identifier":"OPTSTKACC30-09-2021PE1400.00",
"openInterest":0,
"changeinOpenInterest":0,
"pchangeinOpenInterest":0,
"totalTradedVolume":0,
"impliedVolatility":0,
"lastPrice":0,
"change":0,
"pChange":0,
"totalBuyQuantity":8000,
"totalSellQuantity":500,
"bidQty":3000,
"bidprice":0.15,
"askQty":500,
"askPrice":2,
"underlyingValue":2467.9
}
},
{
"strikePrice":1420,
"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021",
"CE":{
"strikePrice":1420,
"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021",
"underlying":"ACC",
"identifier":"OPTSTKACC30-09-2021 CE1420.00",
"openInterest":0,
"changeinOpenInterest":0,
"pchangeinOpenInterest":0,
"totalTradedVolume":0,
"impliedVolatility":0,
"lastPrice":0,
"change":0,
"pChange":0,
"totalBuyQuantity":10000,
"totalSellQuantity":10000,
"bidQty":10000,
"bidprice":915.3,
"askQty":10000,
"askPrice":1192,
"underlyingValue":2467.9
},
"PE":{
"strikePrice":1420,
"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021",
"underlying":"ACC",
"identifier":"OPTSTKACC30-09-2021PE1420.00",
"openInterest":0,
"changeinOpenInterest":0,
"pchangeinOpenInterest":0,
"totalTradedVolume":0,
"impliedVolatility":0,
"lastPrice":0,
"change":0,
"pChange":0,
"totalBuyQuantity":5000,
"totalSellQuantity":0,
"bidQty":5000,
"bidprice":0.1,
"askQty":0,
"askPrice":0,
"underlyingValue":2467.9
}
},
{
"strikePrice":1440,
"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021",
"PE":{
"strikePrice":1440,
"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021",
"underlying":"ACC",
"identifier":"OPTSTKACC30-09-2021PE1440.00",
"openInterest":0,
"changeinOpenInterest":0,
"pchangeinOpenInterest":0,
"totalTradedVolume":0,
"impliedVolatility":0,
"lastPrice":0,
"change":0,
"pChange":0,
"totalBuyQuantity":500 0,
"totalSellQuantity":0,
"bidQty":5000,
"bidprice":0.1,
"askQty":0,
"askPrice":0,
"underlyingValue":2467.9
},
"CE":{
"strikePrice":1440,
"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021",
"underlying":"ACC",
"identifier":"OPTSTKACC30-09-2021CE1440.00",
"openInterest":0,
"changeinOpenInterest":0,
"pchangeinOpenInterest":0,
"totalTradedVolume":0,
"impliedVolatility":0,
"lastPrice":0,
"change":0,
"pChange":0,
"totalBuyQuantity":10000,
"totalSellQuantity":10000,
"bidQty":10000,
"bidprice":902.7,
"askQty":10000,
"askPrice":1170.6,
"underlyingValue":2467.9
}
},
{
"strikePrice":1460,
"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021",
"PE":{
"strikePrice":1460,
"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021",
"underlying":"ACC",
"identifier":"OPTSTKACC30-09-2021PE1460.00",
"openInterest":0,
"changeinOpenInterest":0,
"pchangeinOpenInterest":0,
"totalTradedVolume":0,
"impliedVolatility":0,
"lastPrice":0,
"change":0,
"pChange":0,
"totalBuyQuantity":5000,
"totalSellQuantity":0,
"bidQty":5000,
"bidprice":0.1,
"askQty":0,
"askPrice":0,
"underlyingValue":2467.9
},
"CE":{
"strikePrice":1460,
"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021",
"underlying":"ACC",
"ident ifier":"OPTSTKACC30-09-2021CE1460.00",
"openInterest":0,
"changeinOpenInterest":0,
"pchangeinOpenInterest":0,
"totalTradedVolume":0,
"impliedVolatility":0,
"lastPrice":0,
"change":0,
"pChange":0,
"totalBuyQuantity":10000,
"totalSellQuantity":10000,
"bidQty":10000,
"bidprice":891.15,
"askQty":10000,
"askPrice":1148.85,
"underlyingValue":2467.9
}
},
{
"strikePrice":1480,
"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021",
"CE":{
"strikePrice":1480,
"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021",
"underlying":"ACC",
"identifier":"OPTSTKACC30-09-2021CE1480.00",
"openInterest":0,
"changeinOpenInterest":0,
"pchangeinOpenInterest":0,
"totalTradedVolume":0,
"impliedVolatility":0,
"lastPrice":0,
"change":0,
"pChange":0,
"totalBuyQuantity":10000,
"totalSellQuantity":10000,
"bidQty":10000,
"bidprice":856.25,
"askQty":10000,
"askPrice":1119.45,
"underlyingValue":2467.9
},
"PE":{
"strikePrice":1480,
"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021",
"underlying":"ACC",
"identifier":"OPTSTKACC30-09-2021PE1480.00",
"openInterest":0,
"changeinOpenInterest":0,
"pchangeinOpenInterest":0,
"totalTradedVolume":0,
"impliedVolatility":0,
"lastPric e":0,
"change":0,
"pChange":0,
"totalBuyQuantity":5000,
"totalSellQuantity":0,
"bidQty":5000,
"bidprice":0.1,
"askQty":0,
"askPrice":0,
"underlyingValue":2467.9
}
},
{
"strikePrice":1500,
"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021",
"CE":{
"strikePrice":1500,
"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021",
"underlying":"ACC",
"identifier":"OPTSTKACC30-09-2021CE1500.00",
"openInterest":0,
"changeinOpenInterest":0,
"pchangeinOpenInterest":0,
"totalTradedVolume":0,
"impliedVolatility":0,
"lastPrice":0,
"change":0,
"pChange":0,
"totalBuyQuantity":10000,
"totalSellQuantity":10000,
"bidQty":10000,
"bidprice":851.4,
"askQty":10000,
"askPrice":1096.55,
"underlyingValue":2467.9
},
"PE":{
"strikePrice":1500,
"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021",
"underlying":"ACC",
"identifier":"OPTSTKACC30-09-2021PE1500.00",
"openInterest":3,
"changeinOpenInterest":0,
"pchangeinOpenInterest":0,
"totalTradedVolume":0,
"impliedVolatility":0,
"lastPrice":0.15,
"change":0,
"pChange":0,
"totalBuyQuantity":11500,
"totalSellQuantity":1000,
"bidQty":1500,
"bidprice":0.25,
"askQty":1000,
"askPrice":2,
"underlyingValue":2467.9
}
},
{
"strikePrice":1520,
"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021",
"CE":{
"strikePrice":1520,
"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021",
"underlying":"ACC",
"identifier":"OPTSTKACC30-09-2021CE1520.00",
"openInterest":0,
"changeinOpenInterest":0,
"pchangeinOpenInterest":0,
"totalTradedVolume":0,
"impliedVolatility":0,
"lastPrice":0,
"change":0,
"pChange":0,
"totalBuyQuantity":10000,
"totalSellQuantity":10000,
"bidQty":10000,
"bidprice":833.9,
"askQty":10000,
"askPrice":1061.2,
"underlyingValue":2467.9
},
"PE":{
"strikePrice":1520,
"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021",
"underlying":"ACC",
"identifier":"OPTSTKACC30-09-2021PE1520.00",
"openInterest":0,
"changeinOpenInterest":0,
"pchangeinOpenInterest":0,
"totalTradedVolume":0,
"impliedVolatility":0,
"lastPrice":0,
"change":0,
"pChange":0,
"totalBuyQuantity":5000,
"totalSellQuantity":0,
"bidQty":5000,
"bidprice":0.1,
"askQty":0,
"askPrice":0,
"underlyingValue":2467.9
}
},
{
"strikePrice":1540,
"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021",
"CE":{
"strikePrice":1540,
"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021",
"underlying":"ACC",
"identifier":"OPTSTKACC30-09-2021CE1540.00",
"openInterest":0,
"changeinOpenIn terest":0,
"pchangeinOpenInterest":0,
"totalTradedVolume":0,
"impliedVolatility":0,
"lastPrice":0,
"change":0,
"pChange":0,
"totalBuyQuantity":10000,
"totalSellQuantity":10000,
"bidQty":10000,
"bidprice":823.85,
"askQty":10000,
"askPrice":1062.8,
"underlyingValue":2467.9
},
"PE":{
"strikePrice":1540,
"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021",
"underlying":"ACC",
"identifier":"OPTSTKACC30-09-2021PE1540.00",
"openInterest":0,
"changeinOpenInterest":0,
"pchangeinOpenInterest":0,
"totalTradedVolume":0,
"impliedVolatility":0,
"lastPrice":0,
"change":0,
"pChange":0,
"totalBuyQuantity":5000,
"totalSellQuantity":0,
"bidQty":5000,
"bidprice":0.1,
"askQty":0,
"askPrice":0,
"underlyingValue":2467.9
}
},
{
"strikePrice":1560,
"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021",
"CE":{
"strikePrice":1560,
"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021",
"underlying":"ACC",
"identifier":"OPTSTKACC30-09-2021CE1560.00",
"openInterest":0,
"changeinOpenInterest":0,
"pchangeinOpenInterest":0,
"totalTradedVolume":0,
"impliedVolatility":0,
"lastPrice":0,
"change":0,
"pChange":0,
"totalBuyQuantity":10000,
"totalSellQuantity":10000,
"bidQty":10 000,
"bidprice":803.75,
"askQty":10000,
"askPrice":1029.95,
"underlyingValue":2467.9
},
"PE":{
"strikePrice":1560,
"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021",
"underlying":"ACC",
"identifier":"OPTSTKACC30-09-2021PE1560.00",
"openInterest":0,
"changeinOpenInterest":0,
"pchangeinOpenInterest":0,
"totalTradedVolume":0,
"impliedVolatility":0,
"lastPrice":0,
"change":0,
"pChange":0,
"totalBuyQuantity":5000,
"totalSellQuantity":0,
"bidQty":5000,
"bidprice":0.1,
"askQty":0,
"askPrice":0,
"underlyingValue":2467.9
}
},
```

Attaching my Macro Codes

```
Sub Market_Depth_Pull_JSON()
'Microsoft Scripting Run Time
'Win HTTP Services Version 5.1


Dim JSON, colObj, Item As Object
Dim J As Integer

Dim sURL As String
sURL = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-equities?symbol=ACC"


'Fetching Gainer Responsive Text Start--------------------------------
 Dim httpObject As Object
 Dim sGetResult As String
 Set httpObject = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")



 httpObject.Open "GET", sURL, False
 httpObject.send
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
 sGetResult = httpObject.responseText
 
  'Debug.Print sGetResult
  'Range("I24").Value = sGetResult

Set JSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(sGetResult)
 Set colObj = JSON("records")("data")("CE")
  
 'Debug.Print colObj.Count

 For Each Item In colObj

      For J = 0 To Item.Count - 1
              Debug.Print Item.Items()(J)
         Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Any one please help to extract the data to excel from Json Data

Comment: Your example json has some spurious spaces in it which have to be removed before it can be parsed properly. For example `"totalBuyQuantity":500 0` and
`"ident ifier":"OPTSTKACC30-09-2021CE1460.00"`

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the items in `JSON("records")("data")` and select those where `item("expiryDate") = "30-Sep-2021"`. Extract the values e.g. `item("CE")("strikePrice")`

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Market_Depth_Pull_JSON()

    Dim sGetResult As String

    '---------- replace this with http.request
    Dim fso As Object, ts As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.opentextfile("C:\temp\so\69055825.json")
    sGetResult = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    '-----------
    
    Dim JSON, colObj, item As Object
    Dim ar, cols, i As Integer, j As Integer, r As Long, offset As Integer
    ar = Array("CE", "PE")
    cols = Array("strikePrice", "expiryDate", "underlying", "identifier", "openInterest", _
          "changeinOpenInterest", "pchangeinOpenInterest", "totalTradedVolume", _
          "impliedVolatility", "lastPrice", "change", "pChange", "totalBuyQuantity", _
          "totalSellQuantity", "bidQty", "bidprice", "askQty", "askPrice", "underlyingValue")

    Set JSON = VBAProject.ParseJson(sGetResult)
    Set colObj = JSON("records")("data")
  
    ' results to sheet1
    With Sheet1
        .Range("A1") = ar(0)
        .Range("A2:S2") = cols
        .Range("T1") = ar(1)
        .Range("T2:AL2") = cols
    End With
    r = 3
    For Each item In colObj
        If item("expiryDate") = "30-Sep-2021" Then
           For i = 0 To UBound(ar)
                offset = i * (UBound(cols) + 1)
                For j = 0 To UBound(cols)
                    Sheet1.Cells(r, j + 1 + offset) = item(ar(i))(cols(j))
                Next
            Next
            r = r + 1
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox "Results on sheet1"

End Sub
```