# How do you use SQL Server to convert json to a flat file (table) format?

Tags: json, sql-server, chain

I am using option chain output from TD Ameritrade and would like to access various values such as bid, ask, etc. and the symbol and price from underlying header.

My problem seems to be the date and strike price are keys and not fixed.

The JSON format looks as follows:

(*I couldn't post my question the json text looked like code... not sure how to post that*)

The output I desire should look like this:

```
symbol   underlyingprice    putCall   expdate       strike    bid   ask
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
AMZN     90.965             PUT       2023-03-17:6  90.0      1.83  1.88
AMZN     90.965             PUT       2023-03-17:6  91.0      2.27  2.36
  .
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! As a new user you might wish to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to understand how the site works and then read through the [Markdown Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to figure out how to insert formatted code and example data into your question. Because there's no standard schema for the data conveyed in JSON format I think it will be very important for you to provide some example JSON, even if it's only a snippet or what constitutes a single record, so that people can provide to you an intelligible/usable response.

Answer (score 1):

In the interests of brevity the JSON in the following code is a much reduced example of the JSON presented in a previous Stack Overflow question, [Parse Nested JSON Data of Share Market Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69055825), which also seems to be using data returned from [Ameritrade's Get Open Chain](https://developer.tdameritrade.com/option-chains/apis/get/marketdata/chains) method:

```sql
declare @json nvarchar(max) = N'{
    "symbol": "AAPL",
    "underlyingPrice": 132.325,
    "putExpDateMap": {
        "2021-01-08:8": {
            "132.0": [
                {
                    "putCall": "PUT",
                    "bid": 2.4,
                    "ask": 2.43,
                    "strikePrice": 132.0
                }
            ],
            "133.0": [
                {
                    "putCall": "PUT",
                    "bid": 2.93,
                    "ask": 2.95,
                    "strikePrice": 133.0
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}';

with putExpDateMapKeys (putExpDate, jsonPath) as (
  select
    [key],
    N'$.putExpDateMap.' + quotename([key], N'"') -- e.g.: '$.putExpDateMap."2021-01-08:8"'
  from openjson(@json, N'$.putExpDateMap')
), strikePriceKeys (putExpDate, jsonPath) as (
  select
    putExpDate,
    N'$.' + quotename(putExpDate, N'"') + N'.' + quotename([key], N'"') -- e.g.: '$."2021-01-08:8"."132.0"'
  from putExpDateMapKeys
  cross apply openjson(@json, jsonPath)
)
select J.symbol, J.underlyingPrice, S.putCall, putExpDate as expdate, S.strikePrice, S.bid, S.ask
from openjson(@json) with (
  symbol nvarchar(4),
  underlyingPrice float,
  putExpDateMap nvarchar(max) as JSON
) J
cross apply strikePriceKeys SPK
outer apply openjson(putExpDateMap, SPK.jsonPath) with (
  putCall nvarchar(4),
  strikePrice float,
  bid float,
  ask float
) S;
```

Which yields the output:

| symbol | underlyingPrice | putCall | expdate | strikePrice | bid | ask |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAPL | 132.325 | PUT | 2021-01-08:8 | 132 | 2.4 | 2.43 |
| AAPL | 132.325 | PUT | 2021-01-08:8 | 133 | 2.93 | 2.95 |

So how does this query work? The property keys inside `putExpDateMap` are dynamic so we cannot use a hardcoded JSON path to access their contents. I use two CTE expressions to enumerate the keys:

1. `putExpDateMapKeys` enumerates the date keys, e.g.: `"2021-01-08:8"`
2. within each date key (since I assume there could be more than one) `strikePriceKeys` enumerates the strike price keys, e.g.: `"132.0"` and `"133.0"`

Each CTE expression also returns a JSON path which then allows the final invocation of `openjson()` to access the `putCall`, `bid`, `ask` and `strikePrice` values.

Comment: Well done on identifying the data source +1   ... Shame on OP for not suppling the JSON

Answer (score 0):

An alternative version to Always Learning's great answer which doesn't use dynamic JSON_VALUE which isn't supported in 2016:

```sql
declare @json nvarchar(max) = N'{
    "symbol": "AAPL",
    "underlyingPrice": 132.325,
    "putExpDateMap": {
        "2021-01-08:8": {
            "132.0": [
                {
                    "putCall": "PUT",
                    "bid": 2.4,
                    "ask": 2.43,
                    "strikePrice": 132.0
                }
            ],
            "133.0": [
                {
                    "putCall": "PUT",
                    "bid": 2.93,
                    "ask": 2.95,
                    "strikePrice": 133.0
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}';
select JSON_VALUE(jj, '$.symbol') as symbol
  , JSON_VALUE(jj,'$.underlyingPrice') AS underlyingPrice
  , n.[key] AS date
  , nn.[key] AS strikePrice
  , JSON_VALUE(nn.value, '$[0].putCall') AS pCall
  , JSON_VALUE(nn.value, '$[0].bid') AS bid
  , JSON_VALUE(nn.value, '$[0].ask') AS ask
  , JSON_VALUE(nn.value, '$[0].strikePrice') AS strike
  , nn.value
FROM (
     select @json AS jj
  ) j
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(jj, '$.putExpDateMap') n
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(n.value) nn
```

Here, i'm just shredding every array key and then shredding it's content further down to get the values. I use one assumption, that strikePrice array only contains one row. If not, you can do another level of OPENJSON to get every other row